Flutter - OpenSSL Bitcode is not working for Xcode 16 Builds
I'm trying to upload a new build to AppStore after updating to Xcode 16, but unfortunately I keep getting this issue from the Xcode uploader:

Asset validation failed (90482) Invalid Executable. The executable
'Runner.app/Frameworks/OpenSSL.framework/OpenSSL' contains bitcode.
(ID: 769a1928-0b74-4b3d-b58a-0cb36799d1df)

I've tried many possible solutions, like strip the bitcode manually, and change the Enable_Bitcode to be NO. But nothing worked.
Everytime I try to strip the bitcode for the OpenSSL, I'm getting this message from the terminal:

can't map file:
/Users/XXXX/XXX/ios/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/Frameworks/OpenSSL.xcframework
(Invalid argument) Integrating client project

Any suggestions?
I'm using Flutter 3.16.1, and I'm not willing to update at the moment.

Are you using precompiled OpenSSL? Like from Cocoapods / Swift package manager ?

[Solved] This Answer Fixed My Issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/79030093 but Additonally need to add Framework Details Like Here i am Writting for OpenSSL
Ex : "Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/Frameworks/OpenSSL.xcframework/ios-arm64_arm64e_armv7_armv7s/OpenSSL.framework/OpenSSL"
Follow this for more instructions https://medium.com/@abdulahad2024/fixing-bitcode-issues-in-xcode-16-how-to-resolve-invalid-executable-errors-when-uploading-ios-da07a5a39c7c

On Xcode 16
Add this code inside of post_install
bitcode_strip_path = `xcrun --find bitcode_strip`.chop!
def strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
  framework_path = File.join(Dir.pwd, framework_relative_path)
  command = "#{bitcode_strip_path} #{framework_path} -r -o #{framework_path}"
  puts "Stripping bitcode: #{command}"
  system(command)
end

framework_paths = [
  "Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/Frameworks/OpenSSL.xcframework/ios-arm64_arm64e_armv7_armv7s/OpenSSL.framework/OpenSSL",
  "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/macosx/hermes.framework/hermes",
  "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/macosx/hermes.framework/Versions/Current/hermes",
  "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64/hermes.framework/hermes",
  "Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst/hermes.framework/hermes"
]

framework_paths.each do |framework_relative_path|
  strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
end

Line: Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/Frameworks/OpenSSL.xcframework/ios-arm64_arm64e_armv7_armv7s/OpenSSL.framework/OpenSSL will to resolve your issue
